# UISearchBar's set_cancelButtonText: ivar is prohibited

Tags: swift, ios13

Previously in iOS 12 the same code was allowed, but now when i try to run the same code on iOS 13 it crashes giving me the same error:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSGenericException',
>   reason: 'Access to UISearchBar's set_cancelButtonText: ivar is
>   prohibited. This is an application bug'

Which is related to this line of code:

```
searchController.searchBar.setValue("Cancel".localized, forKey:"_cancelButtonText")
```

Now i know the access of setValue is now prohibited but how is it possible to overcome this crash and change the title of cancel button, since there is no property included in the searchbar.

Comment: Does your app get approved on the AppStore whenever you did this?

Comment: Actually didn't try yet.

Comment: I think this measure Apple took on iOS 13 is better than for you to get hooked with a kind of vague rejection message on app submission. It's against the App Store Review Guidelines to access such APIs. It is illegal

Comment: hope you get a clue now

Comment: i've found a work around.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Instead of messing around with the undocumented view hierarchy, you can use `UIAppearance`:

```
UIBarButtonItem.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf: [UISearchBar.self]).title = "Whatever"
```

Answer (score 4):

Objective-C version:

```
[[UIBarButtonItem appearanceWhenContainedInInstancesOfClasses:@[[UISearchBar class]]] setTitle:@"CancelText"];
```

Answer (score 0):

For **Objective-C** , You can use this if you have problem with UISearchController or change it however you're using.

```
[[UINavigationBar appearanceWhenContainedInInstancesOfClasses:@[[UISearchController class]]] prefersLargeTitles];
```

Answer (score -1):

UISearchDisplayController is deprecated since iOS 8.0
avoid using it