# UISearchBar in iOS 13 have small black spot next to the dismiss (x) button

Tags: ios, ios13

In iOS 13 we're seeing this bug when using the `UISearchBar` (via. the `UISearchController`. Next to the dismiss button (x) there is a small black fragment.

The issue was not present in iOS 12.4.

Using the UI debugger I've identified the issue is caused by us localising the "Cancel" string ourselves (because we want to translate the app in more languages than supported by the Apple System UI), using the following code:

```
UIButton.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf: [UISearchBar.self])
        .setTitle("Cancel", for: .normal)
```

[image: UISearchBar view in iOS 13]

Comment: Maybe you could check the view hierarchy in the debugger to find out what view is half-obscured here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per comments, https://stackoverflow.com/a/58040862/95309 have a fix:

```
UIBarButtonItem.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf: [UISearchBar.self]).title
```

The difference between the `UIButton.appearance` and `UIBarButtonItem.appearance` seems to been the culprit.

Comment: That will crash with you running on iOS 13, accessing set get KVO is now private api.

Comment: @NataMio nope, does not crash on iOS 13. Private APIs (traditionally) start with a underscore, so this is _almost_ a public API.

Comment: @NataMio yeah, that's the underscore version. That's a big difference, since that would access the ivar, not the property.

Comment: but that might change in future i guess your right.

Comment: @NataMio regardless, the suggest in that link works perfectly as well. The difference between the `UIButton.appearance` and `UIBarButtonItem.appearance` seems to do the trick.